# I need all activities in SQL assign to one ID, but currently each activity has three diffrent id

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say that we have `views` table where each activity has three user ID.

- ID1 - user cookie on the server side
- ID2 - user cookie on the browser side
- ID3 - logged in user

I need to assign activity to one id.

Example:

```
ID1 ID2 ID3
-----------
1   A    
1   A
1   B    I
2   B    I
3   C    I
```

During the third activity, user registered account and now I know that all activity concern one user. ID1 and ID2 are cookies ID which are uncertain. ID3 is only when user is registered and logged in. Users don't have to be registered and logged. Users can use the site without an account - but I need information about the whole users activities.

1. How can I count all views and assing to one ID?
   In the above example we can see that 5 views were generated by one user.
2. Is it possible to JOIN another table having the same three ID?

Comment: May you show your result that you expect? It helps more.

Comment: id, count(views)